# Skip some elements in an array through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i'm designing a bus seat layout using jquery. And i done it correctly too.

I'm using an array with seat numbers and i'm getting the seat layout what i want. This is my coding (here '.bus-table' is a table class) :

```
    var row = Array(),i=0, j=0;

    row = [
            ['1','5','9','13','17','21','25','29','33','37','41','45','49'],
            ['2','6','10','14','18','22','26','30','34','38','42','46','50'],
            ['','','','','','','','','','','','','51'],
            ['3','7','11','15','19','23','27','31','35','39','43','47','52'],
            ['4','8','12','16','20','24','28','32','36','40','44','48','53']
        ];

    $.each(row, function(index, value) {
        $('.bus-table').append('<tr>');
            while(j<index+1) {
                for(i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
                    $('.bus-table tr:nth-child('+ (index+1) +')').append(
                        '<td seatno="'+ row[j][i] +'">' + row[j][i] + '<input type="checkbox"/></td>' );
                }
                j++;                                
            }
    });
```

This is my results : [this is my seat layout output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRkwu.jpg)

Now the problem is In 3rd row you can see some checkboxes only. Because in those areas there are no seats in the bus. So, i want to remove those checkboxes, which means in the array (3rd row) i left some blanks, according to those blanks i don't want the checkboxes too. I don't know how to do that. Please help me to solve this case.

(I apologies for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `if` statement inside the `for` loop:

```
for(i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
    if (row[j][i] !== '') {
        $('.bus-table tr:nth-child('+ (index+1) +')').append(
            '<td seatno="'+ row[j][i] +'">' + row[j][i] + '<input type="checkbox"/></td>' );        
    }
    else {
      $('.bus-table tr:nth-child('+ (index+1) +')').append('<td></td>');
    }
}
```

Note the `else` statement, otherwise it will break your table layout

Comment: I have another problem. this is a bus booking seat layout, so we have to disabled the booked seats. Therefore i have an array called `booked_ids = ['24','48','51' ]; ` Now how to make these block of numbered seats to be disabled?? Please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can skip those places using `continue` like shown below:

```
 for(i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
                    if (row[j][i] == ""){
                      '<td seatno="'+ row[j][i] +'">' + row[j][i] + '</td>';
                       continue;//for blank don't make checkbox elements
                    }

                    $('.bus-table tr:nth-child('+ (index+1) +')').append(
                        '<td seatno="'+ row[j][i] +'">' + row[j][i] + '<input type="checkbox"/></td>' );
                }
```

Comment: it's also working but the bus layout is collapsing.. i want '51' numbered seat have to be on the right side.. with your answer that seat is floating to right side.. Anyhow Thanks for your answer Cyril